# Nested case in bash script

Tags: bash, select, scripting, case

I have written the following function in a bash script but it is not working.
Am I missing something obvious?

```
main_menu() {
dialog \
    --title "Sim Gateway Infomation Utility" \
    --menu "What do you want to do?" 12 60 5 \
    Summary "View overall summary" \
    Details "View details of a sim bank" \
    Modify "Modify used minutes of a sim" \
    Exit "Exit" \
    2>$tempfile

retval=$?
case retval in
    0)

        choice=`cat $tempfile`
        case $choice in
            Summary) summary;;
            Details) details;;
            Modify) modify;;
            Exit) clean_up;;
        esac
        ;;
    1)
        confirm_exit;;
    255)
        confirm_exit;;
esac
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2460) discusses `dialog`; I'm not experienced with it.

Your '`case retval in`' needs to be '`case $retval in` (or '`case "$retval" in`).

[*@Idelic notes that my original answer was more conservative than necesssary.*]

The string 'retval' matches none of the options you list in your outer case statement (use a '*' option to detect the unexpected).  The double quotes prevent accidents if `$retval` ever contained spaces; in general, it is a good idea to use double quotes around the variable in `case "$var" in` statements (and most other places too).  In this particular case, it would not matter; the exit status is always a number.  In the '`case "$choice" in`' statement, I'd be more comfortable with the quotes around the variable - but you may still be safe (I'd need to read more about `dialog` to be sure of what it does and whether it ever generates spaces - or nothing even).

Comment: Of course!
many thanks, its amazing how you can look at a script for ages and miss the most obvious typo!

cheers dude!

Comment: The double quotes are not needed for simple "case $VAR in..." statements. There's at least two cases in which you never need the quotes: simple assignment (FOO=$BAR) and the "case ... in" above.

Comment: @Idelic: interesting - I just checked both Korn and Bourne (from Solaris 10) shells, and for assignments you are correct.  I didn't check case.  Somewhere in the last twenty-five years (and it was in the dim distant past rather than within living memory) I got burned by some of this.  Whether that was older versions of shells, or a misunderstanding, or more complicated stuff with 'eval', I don't now remember - it's sad what old age does to you.  I'll reformat the answer a bit to note your comment.