# How to write an if-statement within a if-statement

Tags: bash

How can I write something like:

- `if $1 = a then` check second statement `if $2 is b then echo a and b`
- `else $1 = 1 then` check second statement `if $2 = 2 then echo 1 and 2`

...where all of the variables are strings?

This is what I have:

```
fun() {
  if [ "$1" == "a" ]; # when $1 is a then
  then
    if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is empty string
      echo a
    elif [ "$2" == "b" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is b
    then
      echo "a and b"
     fi
   fi
  else
    if [ "$1" == "1" ]; # when $1 is 1 then
    then
      if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is 1 and $2 is empty string
        echo a
       elif [ "$2" == "2" ]; #$1 is 1 and $2 is 2
       then
         echo "1 and 2"
       fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: Using a nested `case` statement could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477518/nested-case-in-bash-script

Comment: how would i write a switch in this case?, I'm a beginner in coding

Comment: It's called `case` in Bash (`switch` in C-like languages). Follow @eckes' link (that comment should be the (accepted) answer) IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a nested case statement could help you: [Nested case in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477518/nested-case-in-bash-script)

Your function would look like this:

```
fun(){
  case "$1" in
    "a")                      # $1 is 'a'
      case "$2" in
        "")  echo "$1";;      # only $1 present
        "b") echo "a and b";; # $1 is 'a' and $2 is 'b'
      esac;;
    "1")                      # $1 is '1'
      case "$2" in
        "")  echo "$1";;      # only $1 present
        "2") echo "1 and 2";; # $1 is '1' and $2 is '2'
      esac;;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun() {   
  if [ "$1" == "a" ]; # when $1 is a then
  then
    if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is empty string
    then # was missing
      echo a
    elif [ "$2" == "b" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is b
    then
      echo "a and b"
    fi
  # fi # shouldn't be here if you want to have else
  else
    if [ "$1" == "1" ]; # when $1 is 1 then
    then
      if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is 1 and $2 is empty string
      then
        echo a
      elif [ "$2" == "2" ]; #$1 is 1 and $2 is 2
      then
        echo "1 and 2"
      fi
    fi
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"then" should be after each "if" 
`fun() {
  if [ "$1" == "a" ]; # when $1 is a then
  then
    if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is empty string
    then                                    #### 1st omitted "then"
      echo a
    elif [ "$2" == "b" ]; # $1 is a and $2 is b
    then
      echo "a and b"
     fi
 #  fi                                        #### this fi should be in the end
  else
    if [ "$1" == "1" ]; # when $1 is 1 then
    then
      if [ "$2" == "" ]; # $1 is 1 and $2 is empty string
      then                                    #### 2nd omitted "then"
        echo a
       elif [ "$2" == "2" ]; #$1 is 1 and $2 is 2
       then
         echo "1 and 2"
       fi
    fi
fi                                           #### here
}`